# Best practices to completely disable LDAP users' access to mixed services with mixed authentication methods?

Tags: linux, ldap, authentication, openldap, pam

**Background**
We use LDAP in our department to authenticate users to various services including web apps as well as Linux servers (via SSH).  When a user leaves the department, we should disable their access to our services but still retain the account and data, for various reasons.

I thought that simply changing their login shell to something like */bin/false* was sufficient, but I'm still learning about the different aspects to auth for different services, having inherited a rather old and complex cluster of computers.  I've found one other step to take, mentioned below, but that still doesn't address everything.

**Current Process**
  1. Like I mentioned, `loginShell` will be set to `/bin/false`.
  Concerns: Even though the shell is */bin/false*, the password or key is still accepted and access granted for certain amount of clock cycles, since I see things in the security log such as: `sshd: Accepted password`, `Accepted publickey`, and `pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user` (immediately followed by `Received disconnect` and `session closed for user`).
  Exceptions:
    A. This will not prevent access to password-only services, for example web-based services.
    B. There are some servers that have specified the shell to be used, by way of *nslcd* for example, overriding the value of `loginShell`
  2. To address Exception 1A, the `pwdAccountLockedTime` attribute can be added to the account with value `000001010000Z`.

But, Concern-1 and Exception-1B are still not addressed and I'm unsure how to at this point.

**Questions**

- Is Concern-1 anything to really be concerned about?  Is it actually impossible to send any sort of meaningful packet between the 'accepted/session opened' and 'disconnected/session closed' messages?
- For Exception-1B, beside removing the `loginShell` override from `nslcd.conf`, what are suggested solutions to address this unauthorized granted access?  Are there further modifications that can/should be made to *nslcd* or other involved software?
- I'm wondering if there is a better, more streamlined approach to this?
- Also, have I covered everything? or, do you see any gaps in these practices once all concerns and exceptions mentioned are addressed?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you not just disable the user account? If not, does changing the account password sufficiently address your issues?

Comment: Seriously, change the password to a random value.

Comment: @joeqwerty what do you mean "disable"?  That's what I'm trying to figure out!  and no it would not affect the Exception 1B.

Comment: @GregAskew This doesn't address the Exception 1B still.  Further, the idea is to modify the account as little as possible.  If the account should need to be reactivated then the user would need to update their password, which requires knowing the password I set it to, or requires me changing the password again to a temp password and providing it to the user so they can update their password, overall a pain to go though when the password could be left alone.

Comment: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/unix-linux-how-to-lock-or-disable-an-user-account/

Comment: @joeqwerty That only applies to local accounts defined in /etc/passwd, it does not work for LDAP accounts.

Answer (score 0):

͟F͟o͟r͟ ͟E͟x͟c͟e͟p͟t͟i͟o͟n͟-͟1͟B, I finally figured out I could use `AllowGroups` option in `sshd_config` and put a newly created LDAP Group "shellAccess" (for example) there:

```
AllowGroups shellAccess
```

Now, when a user retires, I can just remove their membership in the shellAccess group, it doesn't matter what `loginShell` overrides there are with *nslcd*.

͟T͟h͟i͟s͟ ͟h͟a͟s͟ ͟a͟l͟s͟o͟ ͟a͟d͟d͟r͟e͟s͟s͟e͟d͟ ͟m͟y͟ ͟C͟o͟n͟c͟e͟r͟n͟-͟1 as *sshd* now returns messages such as:

```
sshd: User foo from W.X.Y.Z not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups
sshd: input_userauth_request: invalid user foo
sshd: userauth_pubkey: unsupported public key algorithm: ssh-rsa
sshd: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=W.X.Y.Z  user=foo
sshd: pam_ldap: error trying to bind as user "uid=foo,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com" (Invalid credentials)
sshd: Failed password for invalid user foo from W.X.Y.Z port 666 ssh2
sshd: Connection closed by W.X.Y.Z
```

Best Regards,